How do I connect to my Dropbox account on WSL2?
I have Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS installed as my WSL2 distro on my Windows 11 computer. I've wanted to get my Dropbox folder accessible via my Linux command line. I followed a set of instructions on GitHub on how to install Dropbox on WSL2, found here: Windows WSL2 and Dropbox. I do not mean to be naive, but how do I connect up to my actual Dropbox account? I have provided no information as to what my account is, in the process detailed. To my knowledge, all I've done is install and gotten the program ready to be used on my WSL2 distro. This is likely a very simple thing to do, but I've been away from using Linux and command line/terminal for quite some time now, so I've become very rusty with its usage. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Accessing the Dropbox folder, presumably in a Windows partition, from inside your "WSL2 distro" is one thing; installing and configuring Dropbox for Linux is an entirely different thing. You don't need the latter to do the former. Access anything you need from the Windows side by mounting (example).

Once you download the dropbox program, you have to manually start it for the first time; it will print a unique URL that you visit using your "host" web browser. Log in, and either enter a provided code on the website, or the other way around (or something like that. The process has changed slightly over time, though the general idea has remained the same), and the 'dropbox' process will get an auth token.
After doing this, check dropbox status. If everything works fine, stop the manually-started Dropbox and continue with the systemd "service" setup.

I probably wouldn't recommend running a second copy of Dropbox in WSL2, however – it might be a better idea to use the WSL2-provided direct access to Windows files via /mnt/c/Users.

(For that matter, I wouldn't recommend running Dropbox at all. Unless it has gotten better recently, but in the past, it only kept getting worse, to the point where I moved the whole ~100 GB to Syncthing.)

It's not really my choice, the primary reason I'm doing this is because of a shared project

The whole reason I'm doing this is so that I can use/create symlinks, something not available for Windows Dropbox but works for Linux Dropbox and I can confirm that the symlinks are working in Dropbox on WSL
